# How can I solve a problem with unintended bursts in single-shot mode on my Canon 7D?

Tags: troubleshooting, canon-7d, continuous-drive

Wondering if any of you have heard of this. I've started to experience an intermittent problem with my 7D where the shutter will occasionally fire between two and six times with a single button press. Camera is set for "single" shot and no AEB enabled. Seems to occur mostly when I'm focused on objects that are close (18-24 inches) and then only once in a while. Annoying not because it impacts picture quality but because the unwanted Raw images take up a lot of space on my card. I consulted the experts at Camera West in Rancho Mirage CA because I was sure that I had inadvertently made some type of idiotic modification to a setting but they assured me all settings were OK. Naturally I couldn't duplicate the problem while in the store. Just wondering if any of you have experienced this issue.

Comment: I'm aware this might sound dumb, but... is the firmware up to date?

Comment: Is that "One Shot" on AF or actual "single shot" for the shutter? If the actual shutter setting is set to single and not series but you get a series of photos, I would suggest you clear out your settings and if this doesn't help contact Canon.

Answer (score 6):

I have the 7D and have never experienced this phenomenon.

A couple of things to try:-

- Set camera settings back to factory defaults. (There is a menu option to do this).
- Wipe all custom function settings (not included in the above, I don't think).

Try to replicate the problem after each step above.  If it still exhibits the problem:-

- Remove the main battery. Then in the battery compartment, you will find on the side a 'slide out' bit of plastic containing a little flat round battery.  This is usually responsible for keeping the date/time and settings on the camera when you remove the main battery.  Remove this flat round battery.  Put the camera aside for no less than one hour.  Then when the hour is up, replace the flat round battery, replace the main battery, and turn on the camera.  Note you will need to re-set the date and time etc as if it was brand new.  Try to replicate the problem again.

If the problem still occurs I would take it to an authorised Canon dealer who should be able to send it back to Canon on your behalf to be checked out.  It sounds like it may be an issue with your camera.  If it is less than one year old you should be able to get it fixed or replaced under warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Once in a while, even in single shot mode, my finger get nervous : it "trips" and triggers a second or even a third shot, but 6 it's a lot ?!

Possibly there is a subtle mechanical problem with the shutter button that arises only in specific conditions (for example, does it occur more specifically in portrait or landscape orientation ?).

If you can do without your camera for the time it takes the Canon service to check it, I recommend you send it in. Otherwise live with it, since it doesn't seem like a major issue ?